# Summing rows in Datatable Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier

Tags: vb.net

I keep getting an  error every time i run this code saying `Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier.`  And I don't know what to do. Someone please help

```
  tc = dt1.Compute("Sum(Calories Burned)", "[Runner Name] = '" & Label1.Text & "'")
```

Comment: Do you have a column named "Calories Burned"? Try `Sum([Calories Burned])`

Comment: Yes I do in my database